# How does Magento model distinguish column names in its get/set Model methods?

Tags: magento-1.8, database, model, object

Let's say I have a Model associated to a table with a column called `title`. I understand that I can do a `$model->setTitle("Hello");` to set a value to this field. I can probably do the same for reading like so ``$model->getTitle();`.

An example would be:

```
$blogpost = Mage::getModel('weblog/blogpost');
    $blogpost->setTitle('Code Post!');
    $blogpost->setPost('This post was created from code!');
    $blogpost->save();
```

However, what if the column name was `title_name`? I could do it with `$this->getTitleName()` and it worked.

So, I was thinking, **if I could use `getTitleName()` for a column called `title_name`, then what if I had *another* column called `titleName` in the database**? How is Magento going to decide between `titleName` and `title_name`? How is Magento going to know which column I am referring to?

Comment: This is interesting, but I wouldn't give hard time to Magento by creating `titleName` and `title_name` column name, I would make them unique within a table.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri haha... yea, definitely. I guess I was just curious. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a very specific case so let me clear that up for you.

The magic getters/setters are just wrappers for `getData/setData` methods.

So in your case:

- `title_name` can be retrieved by using `getData('title_name')`
- `titleName` can be retrieved by using `getData('titleName')`

However, if you call `getTitleName()` it will automatically retrieve the `title_name` column.

Here's why.

**Those magic getters/setters are defined in the `Varien_Object` class as well as two other magic methods `has` and `uns`**:

```
public function __call($method, $args)
{
    switch (substr($method, 0, 3)) {
        case 'get' :
            //Varien_Profiler::start('GETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
            $data = $this->getData($key, isset($args[0]) ? $args[0] : null);
            //Varien_Profiler::stop('GETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            return $data;

        case 'set' :
            //Varien_Profiler::start('SETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
            $result = $this->setData($key, isset($args[0]) ? $args[0] : null);
            //Varien_Profiler::stop('SETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            return $result;

        case 'uns' :
            //Varien_Profiler::start('UNS: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
            $result = $this->unsetData($key);
            //Varien_Profiler::stop('UNS: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            return $result;

        case 'has' :
            //Varien_Profiler::start('HAS: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
            //Varien_Profiler::stop('HAS: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            return isset($this->_data[$key]);
    }
    throw new Varien_Exception("Invalid method ".get_class($this)."::".$method."(".print_r($args,1).")");
}
```

As you can see the `_underscore()` method is called on the attribute of the method called.

```
protected function _underscore($name)
{
    if (isset(self::$_underscoreCache[$name])) {
        return self::$_underscoreCache[$name];
    }
    #Varien_Profiler::start('underscore');
    $result = strtolower(preg_replace('/(.)([A-Z])/', "$1_$2", $name));
    #Varien_Profiler::stop('underscore');
    self::$_underscoreCache[$name] = $result;
    return $result;
}
```

So in your case, the code that runs would be:

```
strtolower(preg_replace('/(.)([A-Z])/', "$1_$2", "TitleName"))
```

Which returns `title_name`

**So `getTitleName()` will always get you this column and thus the only way to get `titleName` is by calling `getData('titleName')`**

Answer (score 2):

Convention is to use `lower_snake_case` for columns and `CamelCase` in the getters and setters. Best follow these conventions to not run into weird problems.

It's **possible** to use `getData($columName)` and `setData($columnName, $value)` to access arbitrary column names but I highly recommend following the convention.

<sup>(it's also possible to access `title_name` with `getTitle_name()` but don't do everything that is possible just because you can. This is not the intended usage!)</sup>